# Why when im installing react app, it gives me this error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

So I don't know what's going with my computer, everyone I ask is saying this is strange and they never seen it before so I hoping someone here can help me before i just buy another computer lol...jk

This screenshot you see here is what happens after i run "npm create-react-app

idk why it just stays there and **it only gives three files instead of giving me all the file i need for the react app (like public, SRC)**.

If someone sends me the folder with all the correct files Im able to run the react app and work on it, the issue is that Im not being able to create for some reason and my OCD is really killing me on this.

Please and thank you! :)

```
$ npx create-react-app myapp13
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\joesa\Desktop\myapp13.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...

[2/4] Fetching packages...

info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.

info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. 

Excluding it from installation.

info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.

info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. 

Excluding it from installation.

[3/4] Linking dependencies...

warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".

[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Saved lockfile.

success Saved 14 new dependencies.

info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
└─ react@16.13.1

info All dependencies
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.10.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.10.1
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
├─ react-dev-utils@10.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.7
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
├─ react@16.13.1
└─ scheduler@0.19.1

Done in 12.46s.
```

Comment: How can I not worry about them if it doesn't work properly for me ?

Comment: mention your  node version?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J-z39UQdqV5GP096TDs70m-WzJRiq_bY?usp=sharing

Make sure to run `npm install`

Comment: This works, my friend did the same thing for. My thing is that i want to be able to do this on my own. Its just my OCD thats borthering on why i can do it my self in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app@latest
npx create-react-app testApp
```